# Can i use a variable in oracle sql script?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am using a SQL script to spool data and load data into XML

I want to check whether I can use variable in the SQL script which get it value from another SQL query.

Something like this:

```
var1= select count(1) from emp

spool filename


select * from dept where empcnt=var1
```

Will it work? Is this the best way or any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQLplus, and you only want SQL ( not PLSQL) you can do something like the following, with [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#SQPUG453):

```
spool  yourFile
variable var1 number
select count(1) into :var1 from dual;
select * from dual where rownum = :var1;
```

Another way could be with [substitution variables](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia):

```
spool yourFile
column var1 new_value valueFor_var1
select count(1) as valueFor_var1 from dual;
select * from dual where rownum = &var1;
```

If you can use a PLSQL block, you can do:

```
spool yourFile
declare
    var1 number;
    vDummy varchar2(100);
begin
    select count(1) into var1 from dual;
    select dummy into vDummy from dual where rownum = var1;
    dbms_output.put_line(vDummy);
end;
/
```